# Problema al enviar datos a servidor

Tags: php, mysqli

he creado este código para enviar datos desde una base de datos local a la base de datos de una página web. El problema es que es para un programa de código abierto y de la manera en la que lo he hecho se puede ver la dirección del server, contraseña... (Lo adjunto) 
Buscando un poco he encontrado el código que adjunto al final, que creo que sería la mejor manera de hacerlo pero no acabo de comprender como funciona.

Este es el código que yo he creado:

```
<?php

require_once(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))).'/config.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/config.php');

CheckTourSession(false);

require_once('Common/Fun_FormatText.inc.php');
require_once('Common/Lib/Obj_RankFactory.php');
include('Common/Templates/head.php');


 $codigo = $_GET['s_competition_code'];

$servername1 = "localhost";
$database1 = "ianseo";
$username1 = "root";
$password1 = "";
// Crear conexion
$conn1 = mysqli_connect("localhost", "ianseo", "ianseo", "ianseo");
// Verificar conexion
if (!$conn1) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "";

$sql1 = mysqli_query($conn1,"SELECT * FROM tournament WHERE ToCode= '$codigo' ") or die ("Error: $sql1");
$mostrar = mysqli_fetch_all($sql1,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$servername = "s";
$database = "dn";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
// Crear conexion
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
//Verificar conexion
if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "";
mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM `asirio_Resultados`.`comp` WHERE `comp`.`code` = '$codigo'");
foreach($mostrar as $campo=>$r)
    mysqli_query($conn,"
        INSERT INTO comp (nombre, code, Ubicacion, Fecha, Organizador)
            VALUES ('".$r['ToName']."', '".$r['ToCode']."', '".$r['ToWhere']."', '".$r['ToWhenFrom']."', '".$r['ToComDescr']."')
    ");
?>
```

Y este el segundo código del que hablo:

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))).'/config.php');

CheckTourSession(true);

require_once('Common/Fun_FormatText.inc.php');
require_once('Common/Lib/Obj_RankFactory.php');

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/config.php');
$url = $swe_url_result;

// Read post_body for json data
$request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($request_body,true);

//
$my_json_body = array();
$have_data_to_send = false;
// Send qvalification round

if ($data['option']['ind_kval'] == 1) {
    $data['qualification'] = getIndQualification();
    $have_data_to_send = true;
}
// Send finL round

if ($data['option']['ind_final'] == 1) {
    $data['final'] = getIndFinals();
    $have_data_to_send = true;
}
unset($data['option']);

if ($have_data_to_send) {
    echo sendInformation($url, json_encode($data));
} else {
    $rdata = array('status'=>'Failed','message'=>'Ingen data att skicka.');
    echo json_encode($rdata);
}



function getIndQualification() {
    //.
    $options=array();
    $rank=Obj_RankFactory::create('DivClass',$options);
    $rank->read();
    return prepareIndQualification($rank->getData());
}

function getIndFinals() {
    //.
    $options=array();
    $rank=Obj_RankFactory::create('FinalInd',$options);
    $rank->read();
    $rankData=$rank->getData();
    if (count($rankData['sections']) > 0)
    {
        return prepareIndFinals($rankData);
    }
    return "";
}

function prepareIndQualification($data) {
    $sektions = array();
    foreach ($data['sections'] as $key => $value) {
        $item = array();
        foreach($value['items'] as $ikey => $ivalue) {
            $item[] = array(
                'bib'=> $ivalue['bib'],
                'familyname' => $ivalue['familyname'],
                'givenname' => $ivalue['givenname'],
                'gender' => $ivalue['gender'],
                'div' => $ivalue['div'],
                'class' => $ivalue['class'],
                'ageclass' => $ivalue['ageclass'],
                'subclass' => $ivalue['subclass'],
                'clubId' => $ivalue['countryCode'],
                'clubName' => $ivalue['countryName'],
                'rank' => $ivalue['rank'],
                'score' => $ivalue['score'],
                'gold' => $ivalue['gold'],
                'xnine' => $ivalue['xnine'],
                'dist_1' => $ivalue['dist_1'],
                'dist_2' => $ivalue['dist_2'],
                'dist_3' => $ivalue['dist_3'],
                'dist_4' => $ivalue['dist_4'],
                'dist_5' => $ivalue['dist_5'],
                'dist_6' => $ivalue['dist_6'],
                'dist_7' => $ivalue['dist_7'],
                'dist_8' => $ivalue['dist_8']
            );
        }

        $sektions[] = array('q_class' => $key, 'q_results' => array(
            'q_meta' => array(
                'descr' => $value['meta']['descr'],
                'numdist' => $value['meta']['numDist'],
                'maxArrows' => $value['meta']['maxArrows'],
                'score' => $value['meta']['fields']['score'],
                'gold' => $value['meta']['fields']['gold'],
                'xnine' => $value['meta']['fields']['xnine'],
                'dist_1' => $value['meta']['fields']['dist_1'],
                'dist_2' => $value['meta']['fields']['dist_2'],
                'dist_3' => $value['meta']['fields']['dist_3'],
                'dist_4' => $value['meta']['fields']['dist_4'],
                'dist_5' => $value['meta']['fields']['dist_5'],
                'dist_6' => $value['meta']['fields']['dist_6'],
                'dist_7' => $value['meta']['fields']['dist_7'],
                'dist_8' => $value['meta']['fields']['dist_8']
            ),
            'q_items' => $item
        ));
    }
    return $sektions;
}

function prepareIndFinals($data) {
    $returnData = array();
    foreach ($data['sections'] as $key => $value) {
        $item = array();
        foreach($value['items'] as $ikey => $ivalue) {
            $currentFinals = array();
            foreach($ivalue['finals'] as $fkey => $fvalue) {
                $currentFinals[$fkey] = array(
                    'score' => $fvalue['score'],
                    'setScore' => $fvalue['setScore'],
                    'tie' => $fvalue['tie'],
                    'tiebreak' => $fvalue['tiebreak'],
                    'oppAthlete' => $value['items'][$fvalue['oppAthlete']]['bib'],
                    'oppScore' => $fvalue['oppScore'],
                    'oppSetScore' => $fvalue['oppSetScore'],
                    'oppTie' => $fvalue['oppTie'],
                    'oppTiebreak' => $fvalue['oppTiebreak']
                );
            }

            $item[] = array(
                'bib'=> $ivalue['bib'],
                'familyname' => $ivalue['familyname'],
                'givenname' => $ivalue['givenname'],
                'gender' => $ivalue['gender'],
                'clubId' => $ivalue['countryCode'],
                'clubName' => $ivalue['countryName'],
                'rank' => $ivalue['rank'],
                'elims' => $ivalue['elims'],
                'finals' => $currentFinals
            );
        }
        unset($value['meta']['fields']['finals']['fields']);
        $returnData[] = array('f_class' => $key, 'f_results' => array(
            'f_meta' => array(
                'descr' => $value['meta']['descr'],
                'firstPhase' => $value['meta']['firstPhase'],
                'elim1' => $value['meta']['fields']['elim1'],
                'elim2' => $value['meta']['fields']['elim2'],
                'finals' => $value['meta']['fields']['finals']
            ),
            'f_items' => $item
        ));
    }
    return $returnData;
}

function sendInformation($url, $data) {
    $hand = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($hand, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($hand, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($hand, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($hand, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($hand, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($hand, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
    $result = curl_exec($hand);
    curl_close($hand);
    return $result;
}
?>
```

Para intentar aclarar un poco lo que quiero hacer:
Estoy intentando hacer para un club deportivo una adaptación de un programa de gestión de resultados de tiro con arco. Lo que necesito es coger los datos de las puntuaciones que tengo en la base de datos del programa y subirlos a la base de datos de la web para que se puedan seguir las puntuaciones en directo. Más o menos tengo idea de como hacerlo pero en algunos puntos de la programación me pierdo.

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Comment: No me queda nada claro cual es el problema en particular que tenes

Comment: Pues necesito subir a la base de datos de la web los datos pero no se como hacerlo

Comment: El codigo que escribiste no funciona? Tira algun error?

Comment: No, no tiene ningún error, pero queda visible la dirección del server y la contraseña...
Entonces buscando encontré el segundo código en un programa similar al q intento hacer pero no comprendo como funciona

Comment: Ah ah.. pero el segundo codigo es para hacer un curl.. no una conexion a una base de datos.. o sea que tu pregunta es como guardar los datos de configuracion de tu aplicacion fuera de tu codigo?

Comment: O sea, no es un problema al enviar datos al servidor...

Comment: Esq con el segundo código entiendo que los datos llegan a una página del server, pero no se que código tiene que tener esta pagina para poder guardar los datos en ma base de datos de la página

Comment: Esa pagina tiene que ser un controlador de back que reciba la llamada y haga lo que tiene que hacer. Puede ser en cuaquier lenguaje

Comment: Podría hacerme un pequeño ejemplo de como sería?

Comment: No logro entender del todo el problema, pero me pregunto por qué no creas un sistema de login con nombre de usuario/contraseña y cuando el usuario entre correctamente le muestras los datos que hay en la base de datos.